# Tkinter multi-parent class not initialising

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on overhauling Tkinter to do a few extra things. To facilitate this I have created a bunch of classes for each of the widgets along with a base class for global methods.

The issue I am having is the global class not being initialised when using the super() method in one of the widgets due to the lack of a `super()` call being made in the base Tkinter widgets and framework.

```py
from tkinter import *
from uuid import uuid4
class baseWidget:
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        print("baseWidget Initialised")
        self.__unique_id = uuid4() ##example why its needed

class a:
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        print("a Initialised")
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

class cFrame(Frame, baseWidget):
#class cFrame(a, baseWidget):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super(cFrame, self).__init__(master, **kwargs)
        #baseWidget.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

a=1
if a:
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("400x400")
    f = cFrame(root, bg="red")
    f.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, expand=1)

    b = Button(f, text="submit")
    b.pack(side=TOP)

    root.mainloop()
else:
    cFrame('test', a=1, b=2)
```

In the above code there are 2 toggle states, set a=0 and switch the cFrame class comments around for the correct implementation of how it **should** work (noted as s1), or leave them as shown to see the current issue (noted as s2).

In s1 both class `a` and class `baseWidget` are called (with class `a` being a stand-in for `Frame`) and both classes are initialised.

In s2 class `Frame` is initialised but class `baseWidget` is not initialised, however methods available to `baseWidget` are available to the child class.

As a work around I did create a second method:

```py
def __xinit__(self, master, **kwargs):
    super(cFrame, self).__init(master, **kwargs)
    baseWidget.__init__(self, master, **kwarhs)
```

And switch the standard `super()` call from my `__init__` method to instead call `__xinit__`, however this solution requires that I modify every class to include this workaround with a lot of copy-paste code.

I am hoping to find a better solution to initialise both classes without bloating the code with the same method throughout.

Comment: The combination of `super()` and multiple inheritance only works if *every* class in the hierarchy uses `super()` - including the base classes, even those where the use of `super()` doesn't seem necessary.  That isn't the case here, since you have a base class that doesn't do this, and isn't under your control - so you simply can't use `super()`.  `cFrame.__init__()` should explicitly call `__init__()` on both of its parent classes.

Comment: It's somewhat unclear. Why do you need multiple base classes? If you are not hacking Tkinter, don't do that. If you want to hack Tkinter, do a monkey-patching on the ```tkinter.BaseWidget``` class. If you insist multiple base classes, just change the MRO like ```class cFrame(baseWidget, Frame):```.

Comment: following the parent tree of a tkinter Frame `Frame->Widget->(Pack, Place, Grid), BaseWidget->Misc`. Misc, Pack, Place, Grid has no __init__ so not sure how i would add in the super() call to those. adding `super().__init__(master, widgetName, cnf=cnf, kw=kw, extra=extra)` to the BaseWidget creates the following error `TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)`. My goal is to add a collection of methods to all widgets I am customising while keeping all tkinter methods availble.